# Data.table grouping result not in correct order

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the data.table command below that is supposed to perform similarly to the ddply counterpart:

```
DT[,mean(var),by=group]
```

VS.

```
ddply(DF,.(group), summarise, mean(var))
```

Where `levels(group)` gives `"1","2","3","4","5"`.

My question is why `DT` returns a table with the group column not ordered, i.e. it returns:

```
   Group            V1
1-       2  0.0012030079
2-       3  0.0012680941
3-       4 -0.0003243492
4-       5  0.0008718012
5-       1  0.0009910559
```

Instead of the expected and actual output from the ddply command:

```
  Group           ..1
1       1  0.0009910559
2       2  0.0012030079
3       3  0.0012680941
4       4 -0.0003243492
5       5  0.0008718012
```

I am using the workaround `DT[,mean(var),by=group][order(group)]` to return a sorted list, but this is quite painful. Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thanks!

PS. The table that I copied from R console does not seem to be display properly here, I am sorry for this. How can I make it display like a table?

Answer (score 4):

As it states under the section for `by=` in `?data.table`:

> "The order of the rows within each group is preserved, as is the order
>   of the groups."

So the expected result is exactly what you got. One more convenient way to deal with the sorting is to use:

```
DT[,mean(var),keyby=group]
```

As per the `?data.table` docs again:

> "It is common practice to use `keyby=` routinely when you wish the
>   result to be sorted."

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. Although I am wondering why ordering by levels was not done by default as is the case for ddply.

Comment: @LukeShi  That would be another question